# how to use variables of a class from other classes in c#

Tags: c#

i need to call variables that are defined in a class

```
class testclasss
{
    public testclass(double[,] values)
    {
        double[][] rawData = new double[10][];  
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            rawData[i] = new double[] { values[i, 2], stockvalues[i, 0] };  // if data won't fit into memory, stream through external storage
        }
        int num = 3;  
        int max = 30; 
    } 

    public int[] checkvalue(double[][] rawData, int num, int maxCount) 
    {
        ............
    }
}
```

I have called constructor using

```
    testclass newk = new testclass(values);
```

now how can i call the function checkvalues(). i tried using newk.num,newk.maxcount but those variables were not recognized.

Comment: You calculate `rawData` in that constructor and then forget about it (variable gets out of scope). Move that rawData into a class-level field to retain the value. Add a property or method to acces it from outside.

Comment: Where is `stockvalues` defined?

Comment: sorry, for stockvalues that was a mistype

Answer (score 3):

Just as your class constructor and checkvalues function are public, so too must the properties you wish to access from outside the class. Put these at the top of your class declaration:

```
public int num {get; set;}
public int max {get; set;}
```

Then you can access them via newk.num and newk.max.

EDIT: In response to your second comment, I think you might be a bit confused about how functions and properties interact within the same class. This might help:

```
class TestClass {
    private int _num;
    private int _max;
    private double[][] _rawData;

    public TestClass(double[,] values, int num, int max) 
    {
        _num = num;
        _max = max;
        _rawData = new double[10][]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            _rawData[i] = new double[] { values[i, 2], stockvalues[i, 0] };
        }
    }

    public int[] CheckValues() 
    {
        //Because _num _max and _rawData exist in TestClass, CheckValues() can access them.
        //There's no need to pass them into the function - it already knows about them.
        //Do some calculations on _num, _max, _rawData.  
        return Something;          
    }
}
```

Then, do this (for example, I don't know what numbers you're actually using):

```
double[,] values = new double[10,10];
int num = 3;
int max = 30;
Testclass foo = new Testclass(values, num, max);
int[] results = foo.CheckValues();
```

Comment: how can i access **double[][] rawData** ??

Comment: The same way - add a public double[][] rawdata {get; set;} to the beginning of your class declaration. You may find this to be illuminating: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx That should explain how to use properties effectively in C#. See also this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx

Comment: i tried declaring 'public double[][] finaldata { get; set; }' but 'int[] cluster = newk.Checkvalue(newk.rawData, newk.num, newk.max);' gave me error. it says TestClass.rawdata is inaccessable due to protection leve

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
class TestClass {

    public int num { get; set; }  
    public int max { get; set; }   

    public double[][] rawData;

    public TestClass(double[,] values)
    {
           rawData = new double[10][];  
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               rawData[i] = new double[] { values[i, 2], stockvalues[i, 0] };  // if data won't fit into memory, stream through external storage
           }
           this.num = 3;  
           this.max = 30; 
     } 

     public int[] CheckValue() 
     {............}      
  }
```

Comment: what about accessing rawdata? i tried declaring 'public double[][] finaldata { get; set; }' but 'int[] cluster = newk.Checkvalue(newk.rawData, newk.num, newk.max);' gave me error. it says _TestClass.rawdata is inaccessable due to protection level_

Comment: Just edited the code. Not sure if you would be trying to access rawData from outside the class. You just had to add "public" before the type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a property with a get accessor.

Here is a simplified example based on your code:

```
class testclass
{
   private int _num = 0;
   private int _max = 0;

   public int Num
   {
      set { _num = value; }
      get { return _num; }
   }

   public int Max
   {
      set { _max = value; }
      get { return _max; }
   }

   public testclass()
   {
            Num = 3;  
            Max = 30; 
   }    
}

//To access Num or Max from a different class:

testclass test = new testclass(null);
Console.WriteLine(test.Num);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using your exact same code, except for **public testclass(double[,] values)**, which I changed to **public testfunction(double[,] values)**

```
class testclass
{
    public testfunction(double[,] values)
    {
        double[][] rawData = new double[10][];  
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        rawData[i] = new double[] { values[i, 2], stockvalues[i, 0] };  // if data won't fit into memory, stream through external storage
        }
        int num = 3;  
        int max = 30; 
    } 

    public int[] checkvalue(double[][] rawData, int num, int maxCount) 
    {
        ............
    }
}
```

Have you tried calling checkvalues() function like this?

```
testclass.checkvalue();
```